# Problem plotting white plot using numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, numpy-ndarray

```
import numpy as np    
import matplotlib as plt

a = np.full((256, 256), 255, dtype=np.float32)
plt.imshow(a, cmap='gray')
```

[image]

I want to plot white plot but it is plotting black. I have also tried 0 and 1 in place of 255 but still getting black plot. Can anyone let me know where I am making mistake?

Comment: With such `cmap` you have to add two other parameters: `plt.imshow(a, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)`

Comment: @Alex can you please explain the reason as well?

Comment: This is just a weird behavior on the part if pyplot when you use this cmap. If you omit this non-default cmap, the issue will disappear even without adding `vmin=0, vmax=255`, but the image will be greenish in style (more artistic in my opinion).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Alex in the comments, in this case you have to provide `vmin=0` and `vmax=255`. Usually, Matplotlib extracts those values from the image. However, since your array has only one single value, 255, then Matplotlib computes `vmin=vmax`, which is effectively going to compress the colormap to a single color.

```py
import numpy as np    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.full((256, 256), 255, dtype=int)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(a, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)
```